# How can you tell if adding a friend to a friendlist will require permission?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

If you add a friend to a list, sometimes it "just works" and for other list types (like Family) Facebook needs to send a confirmation to the user to confirm it.

However, of the list types below it's not clear, or at least I can't find it documented, which happens immediately and which will require additional confirmation.

close_friends, acquaintances, restricted,user_created, education, work, current_city or family

I can make an educated guess, but is there any programmatic indication or documentation?  I have a tool that lets you manage these friend lists, but I have to in certain cases tell the user not to expect anything until the request is approved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a way to check this via the graph API.

As far as I know, only `family` requires a confirmation. Since there are only a few possibilities for the list type, I would go through each and check each type.